# Cocos2d: what happens to the CCDirector when a game exited and then resumed

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am wondering what happens in terms of CCDirector pause and resume calls when the user exists from the App from one of the following reasons:

- the user has tapped the main iPhone button and went back to the main iPhone screen
- the user has clicked a link within the Cocos2d app that opens an URL like this one:
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];

I have noticed that the CCDirector pause and resume are affected somehow but I do not understand where are the hidden calls to those methods.

In other words, in my game when the user presses the pause button I call the       **[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]** method and it seems to work fine. But when the user exits the App for one of the two reasons and then re-enters the App the pause fails (the game has been resumed) because I think that somehow the App has within some "onEnter" method calls to CCDirector resume (or similar). I searched in the workspace but couldn't find. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are down the bottom of AppDelegate.m

**Cocos2d 2.0**

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/templates/Xcode4_templates/cocos2d%20iOS.xctemplate/AppDelegate.m

**Cocos2d 1.0**

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop/templates/Xcode4_templates/cocos2d.xctemplate/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the search because there are some underscore in some director calls. Is it good practice to tweak AppDelegate code?

Comment: As long as the app still pauses when you exit etc, then yeah its fine! A lot of people put saving their game state in those methods so when you close the app in the middle of a game it saves it to disk, not just in memory.